# Sql query to return the count of employees in each department

Tags: sql

I am new to Sql query if I had a table called Employee:

```
Id, Name, Department
 1   tim  sales
 2   tom  sales
 3   jay  HR
 4   ben  design
 5   lin  design
```

I am trying to write a query that returns the number of employees in each department.

```
SELECT COUNT(Department) FROM Employee
```

Does anyone have any advise on how I can improve this query?

****Edit

What about if I wanted to return the number of employees in the same department

Comment: SELECT COUNT(id), department FROM Employee, group by department.

Comment: This is rather basic SQL - I'd advise having a look around the MSDN site on SQL, rather than asking here.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(id), department FROM Employee GROUP BY department;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using group by**
`SELECT COUNT(id), department FROM Employee GROUP BY department`

OR

**By WHERE condition**`SELECT COUNT(id),Department FROM Employee WHERE Department='HR'`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT([id]), [department] FROM [Employee], GROUP BY [department].
```

Comment: This is invalid standard SQL. You should mention the DBMS for which this works (the tag `sql` does not refer to any specific database product)